# grouping td tags within a tr

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to set up a "container" of sorts containing of group of td tags inside fo a tr for better use with jquery.  Basically I want ot display a certain set of tds based on some data that I have generated dynamically and hide other sets of tds.  I've tried using tbody but that doesn't seem to work, and div and span seem to complain that they cannot be nested within element tr.  Is there an appropriate way to do this?

Comment: A container? Like.. a table?

Comment: You could use a class on each td and manipulate them using the class to hold on to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most appropriate way would be to assign each "TD" element a specific class name you can reference later as a selector.

Example:

```
<tr>
  <td>foo</td>
  <td>foo</td>
  <td>foo</td>
  <td class="bar">bar</td>
  <td class="bar">bar</td>
  <td class="bar">bar</td>
  <td>foo</td>
  <td>foo</td>
</tr>

$('td.bar').css({color: 'red'});
```

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/DyJcH/)

Comment: As a side note: If the OP needs to be more specific (i.e. group them in TRs respectivly) he then needs to identify the TR container, either with a class, id, or knowing it's index in the table/tbody.

Comment: I am, apparently, a moron.  I knew about class selectors, just didn't think about assigning a class to more than one element.  grr.  I can see how my question got voted down, that was kind of a dumb question.  Thanks for answering anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to those "groups" and change the visiblity of the td's depending on the class.
For instance, if you add the class "yourClass" to all the ones you don't want to have visible and the set the following CSS statement: `.yourClass{ display:none }` you will not see those td's

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QL7AC/1/).

And you could then select those td's from your table with jQuery by the class itself!

```
$("td.yourClass");
```

Or if you want all the ones that **don't** have the class (an inverse selection) you'd change the selector to `$("td:not(.yourClass.)");` returning all the td's that do **not** have the `yourClass` class.